# prevent sscanf from parsing double as int

Tags: c

When the input string is e.g. "4.5" I want sscanf to not parse it as a integer. But now it does.

My code looks like this:
`if (sscanf(str, "%d", &val) == 0) { return NULL; }`
This does not work of course since sscanf parses "4.5" as 4 and does not return NULL

Thanks for help

Comment: You can read the line into a string and use [strtol](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/).

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is or what your expected results are. Downvote will be removed if the question is amended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sscanf("4.5", "%d", &val)` does not parse "4.5" as 4.  It parses the "4" as 4 and leaves the ".5" unparsed.  You instead could verify that `sscanf` does not parse any additional characters from the string:

```c
int val;
char c;
if (sscanf(str, "%d%c", &val, &c) != 1) { return NULL; }
```

Comment: For example, `sscanf("4xyz", "%d", &val)` stores `4` in `val` and leaves `"xyz"` unparsed.

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf()` will skip leading white space.  It will parse the prefix (in this case `4`) and ignore the suffix (in this case `.5`).   If the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

1. I suggest write a function to parse an integer; you could use `strtol()` with additional boundary checks:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define FS " "

const char *parse_int(const char *s, int *v) {
    if(!s)
        return NULL;
    int sign = 1;
    if(*s == '-') {
        sign = -1;
        s++;
    }
    if(!isdigit(*s))
        return NULL;
    *v = 0;
    for(; isdigit(*s); s++) {
        int d = sign * (*s - '0');
        if(*v < (INT_MIN + d) / 10 || *v > (INT_MAX + d) / 10)
            return NULL;
        *v = *v * 10 + d;
    }
    return s;
}

const char *parse_str(const char *s, const char *expect) {
    if(!s || strncmp(s, expect, strlen(expect)))
        return NULL;
    return s + strlen(expect);
}

int main() {
    const char *str = "4.5 ";
    int d;
    // note: str will be set to NULL on parse failure; use different `const char *` variables to keep track of progress.
    (str = parse_int(str, &d)) &&
    (str = parse_str(str, FS));
    if(!str) {
        printf("parse failed");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Two suggestions if that doesn't work for you:

2. Use `%n` to figure what remains of the string, discard it it's not a field separator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FS " "

int main() {
    char *str = "4.5";
    int val;
    int pos;
    int rv = sscanf(str, "%d%n", &val, &pos);
    if(rv != 1 || strncmp(str + pos, FS, sizeof FS - 1)) {
        printf("parse failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

3. Read a `double` instead of an `int` and check if it's a whole number and in the correct range:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define delta 1e-6

int main() {
    char *str = "4.5";
    double d;
    int rv = sscanf(str, "%lf", &d);
    if(d - (int) d > delta || d > INT_MAX || d < INT_MIN) {
        printf("parse failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Re “ignore the suffix either invalid data or if the number is too large or small”: If the number is too large, the behavior is not defined. C 2018 7.21.6.2 10 says “… if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Updated answer with your clarification, thanks.